# Rails4 upgrade: active record.to_yaml changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded my app to Rails4.

I like to do `puts object.to_yaml` in the console to inspect my objects.

In Rails 3, I would get:

```
puts User.first.to_yaml
--- !ruby/object:User
  id: '1'
  fname: Hello
  lname: World
  email: hello@world.com
  slug: hello-world
  facebook_url: 
  twitter_url: 
  skype_pseudo: 
  website_url: 
  created_at: '2015-06-23 08:20:35.744329'
  updated_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.669312'
  encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FDZgUOmxZCN5dYYCsMO1HuOfe.QfRsFd8XCnGV0DsiIMIwKDR4zoS"
  reset_password_token: 
  reset_password_sent_at: 
  remember_created_at: 
  sign_in_count: '1'
  current_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
  last_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
  current_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
  last_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
```

Whereas in Rails 4, I get all those (useless for me) data:

```
puts User.first.to_yaml
--- !ruby/object:User
raw_attributes:
  id: '1'
  fname: Hello
  lname: World
  email: hello@world.com
  slug: hello-world
  facebook_url: 
  twitter_url: 
  skype_pseudo: 
  website_url: 
  created_at: '2015-06-23 08:20:35.744329'
  updated_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.669312'
  encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FDZgUOmxZCN5dYYCsMO1HuOfe.QfRsFd8XCnGV0DsiIMIwKDR4zoS"
  reset_password_token: 
  reset_password_sent_at: 
  remember_created_at: 
  sign_in_count: '1'
  current_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
  last_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
  current_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
  last_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash
    types:
      id: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer
        precision: 
        scale: 
        limit: 
        range: !ruby/range
          begin: -2147483648
          end: 2147483648
          excl: true
      fname: &1 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String
        precision: 
        scale: 
        limit: 255
      lname: *1
      email: *1
      slug: *1
      home_space_id: *2
      facebook_url: *1
      twitter_url: *1
      skype_pseudo: *1
      website_url: *1
      created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::DateTime
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
      updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: *3
      encrypted_password: *1
      reset_password_token: *1
      reset_password_sent_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: *3
      remember_created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: *3
      sign_in_count: *2
      current_sign_in_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: *3
      last_sign_in_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
        subtype: *3
      current_sign_in_ip: *1
      last_sign_in_ip: *1
    values:
      id: '1'
      fname: Hello
      lname: World
      email: hello@world.com
      slug: hello-world
      facebook_url: 
      twitter_url: 
      skype_pseudo: 
      website_url: 
      created_at: '2015-06-23 08:20:35.744329'
      updated_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.669312'
      encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FDZgUOmxZCN5dYYCsMO1HuOfe.QfRsFd8XCnGV0DsiIMIwKDR4zoS"
      reset_password_token: 
      reset_password_sent_at: 
      remember_created_at: 
      sign_in_count: '1'
      current_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
      last_sign_in_at: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
      current_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
      last_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
    additional_types: {}
    materialized: true
    delegate_hash:
      id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: id
        value_before_type_cast: '1'
        type: *2
      fname: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: fname
        value_before_type_cast: Hello
        type: *1
      lname: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: lname
        value_before_type_cast: World
        type: *1
      email: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: email
        value_before_type_cast: hello@world.com
        type: *1
      slug: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: slug
        value_before_type_cast: hello-world
        type: *1
      facebook_url: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: facebook_url
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: *1
      twitter_url: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: twitter_url
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: *1
      skype_pseudo: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: skype_pseudo
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: *1
      website_url: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: website_url
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: *1
      created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: created_at
        value_before_type_cast: '2015-06-23 08:20:35.744329'
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: updated_at
        value_before_type_cast: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.669312'
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      encrypted_password: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: encrypted_password
        value_before_type_cast: "$2a$10$FDZgUOmxZCN5dYYCsMO1HuOfe.QfRsFd8XCnGV0DsiIMIwKDR4zoS"
        type: *1
      reset_password_token: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: reset_password_token
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: *1
      reset_password_sent_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: reset_password_sent_at
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      remember_created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: remember_created_at
        value_before_type_cast: 
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      sign_in_count: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: sign_in_count
        value_before_type_cast: '1'
        type: *2
      current_sign_in_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: current_sign_in_at
        value_before_type_cast: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      last_sign_in_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: last_sign_in_at
        value_before_type_cast: '2015-08-18 14:54:25.667587'
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *3
      current_sign_in_ip: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: current_sign_in_ip
        value_before_type_cast: 127.0.0.1
        type: *1
      last_sign_in_ip: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: last_sign_in_ip
        value_before_type_cast: 127.0.0.1
        type: *1
new_record: false
active_record_yaml_version: 0
```

Any change I get back the previous behavior or find a way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the output of `to_yaml`, you can override `encode_with`. I had the same problem with an incompatibility upgrading from Rails 4.1 to 4.2 and fixed it with:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def encode_with(coder)
    coder['attributes'] = attributes_before_type_cast
  end
end
```

Where `attributes` is the key in the YAML and `attributes_before_type_cast` is the value. To match the request in the question (where the attributes of the record are immediately under the root of the YAML), this should work:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def encode_with(coder)
    attributes_before_type_cast.each{|k, v| coder[k] = v}
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Though I'd still be curious to understand why it was changed in the first place.

Comment: Problem is that this breaks globalize, I believe globalize uses type_casting to perform there localizations

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
User.first.attributes.to_yaml
```

Comment: Yes that could work. But when it is an array I want to inspect, it becomes even more painful: `User.where(last_name: 'Jobs').map(&:attributes).to_yaml`. If there is no other possibilities, I'll go with that.